# What is the real world example of using on: :new route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I understand that when you create a custom route for a specific member you would use

```
resources :photos do
  get 'preview', on: :member
end
```

and for example if you want to delete a whole collection of comments you would use

```
resources :comments do
      delete :destroy_all, on: :collection
end
```

but in which case would you use on: :new. Can someone give a detailed example instead of just pointing to the docs that just say

> .10.3 Adding Routes for Additional New Actions
>   To add an alternate new action using the :on shortcut:
>
> ```
> resources :comments do
>   get 'preview', on: :new
> end
> ```
>
> This will enable Rails to recognize paths such as /comments/new/preview with GET, and route to the preview action of
>   CommentsController. It will also create the preview_new_comment_url
>   and preview_new_comment_path route helpers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example in the docs is actually a pretty good real world example.

Assume that you have a `Comment` model, which stores users comments.  Furthermore you want to be able to accept new comments and allow the user to preview how their comment will look without having to actually save the comment.

With a standard CRUD controller the flow would be:

- comments/new to render the comment form (form action points to comments/create)
- comments/create to create the comment record

In this scenario there is an additional step:

- comments/new to render the comment form (form action points to comments/new/preview)
- comments/new/preview to preview the comment format before saving it
- comments/create to create the comment record

So `on: :new` allows you to piggy back another action off of the new action. Now, you may be asking yourself, why `on: :new` on not just `on: :collection`?  Because :collection is for routes that operate on all comments, while 'comments/new/preview' clearly operates on a single unsaved comment.

I hope this is clear.  Let me know if I can explain in more detail.

Comment: Why not just on: :member then ?

Comment: Because member requires the :id of a saved record.

Comment: ah ok. missed that part!